# How can I individually replace each occurence of a string?

Tags: swift

I am trying to replace every occurrence of a space with two random characters (out of 103). The problem is that it is always the same 2 characters every time, which makes sense if you look at the code

I'm pretty new to  Swift and Xcode and I've already tried a bunch of things, like using a "for" loop.

```
newSentence = passedSentence.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: " \(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]) \(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]) ")    
resultText.text = newSentence
```

As I said before, it is always the same 2 characters when I want it to "refresh" for every occurrence of a space.

Comment: You need to show clear examples of input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `map(_:)` method instead of `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` to get the desired result.

> `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`
>
> A new string in which all occurrences of target in the receiver are
>   replaced by replacement.

It replaces all the occurrences with the same instance that is passed in the `replacementString` i.e. `randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103) (randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]` is executed only once and used throughout the `string` for all occurrences of `" "`.

```
    let passedSentence = "This is a sample sentence"

    let newSentence = (passedSentence.map { (char) -> String in
        if char == " " {
            return " \(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]) \(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]) "
        }
        return String(char)
    }).joined()

    print(newSentence)
```

In case the you're using the whole range of `randomArray`, i.e. if `randomArray` contains `104 elements i.e. 0...103`, you can directly use [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) on `randomArray` instead of using `random(in:)` on `Int`, i.e.

Use

```
randomArray.randomElement()
```

instead of

```
randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your behavior is expected given your code. The parameter passed in `with:` is only executed once so if it generates "SX", that will be used to replace ALL the occurrences of " "(space) in your `passedSentence`.

To get your expected behavior, you would have to loop:

```
var rangeOfEmptyString = passedSentence.range(of: " ")
while rangeOfEmptyString != nil {
   let randomModifier = "\(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)])\(randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)])"
   passedSentence = passedSentence.replacingCharacters(in: rangeOfEmptyString!, with: randomModifier)
   rangeOfEmptyString = passedSentence.range(of: " ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace each space with different random elements of the array. `replacingOccurrences` method replaces all ranges at once. Get the range of space one by one and replace with unique random elements

```
let randomArray:[String] = ["a","b","c","d"]
var passedSentence = "This is a long text"
var start = passedSentence.startIndex
while let range = passedSentence[start...].rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces),
    let random1 = randomArray.randomElement(),
    let random2 = randomArray.randomElement()  {
    let replacementString = " \(random1) \(random2) "
    passedSentence.replaceSubrange(range, with: " \(random1) \(random2) ")
    start = passedSentence.index(range.upperBound, offsetBy: replacementString.count)
}
print(passedSentence)
```

To get the random element from an array don't use `randomArray[Int.random(in: 0...103)]`. You can use [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement)